# SQLCMD Using Powershell Gives No Response

Tags: sql-server-2019, sqlcmd

I have SQL Server 2019 Standard installed on my Server 2019. I also have installed the SQL CMD Line tools V21.1.18246. When I open my PowerShell in Administrator mode and do a `sqlcmd -?` the command completes without a error but doesn't show anything. I have reinstalled the CMD LINE Tools and repaired the SQL Server install and I still can't get anything from `sqlcmd`. I have nothing in my logs saying there is a failure.

Access to the module location is specified in the Environment Variables on the server. I have also installed [Microsoft Command Line Utilities 15 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) for the server. Also I have run the `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name sqlserver` command and it shows the SQL CMD Line tools module installed in 4 locations. All of those locations are in the environments variables.

So why does sqlcmd -? return nothing?

Comment: From cmd, what does `where sqlcmd` return? It should just be an executable under your SQL Server client installation. You don't need any additional modules to run this, although installing those modules could be giving you access to additional powershell cmdlets

Comment: @AndrewSayer when I do that command nothing happens. it just goes back to c:\windows\system32

Comment: what does `where where` return?  It should typically show `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe`

Comment: @HannahVernon again returns C:\Windows\System\where.exe

Comment: But `where sqlcmd` returns *nothing*?  Very strange.

Comment: If you run in Powershell `where.exe sqlcmd.exe` how many lines do you get back and which paths are used?

Comment: I fixed this issue. Something doesn't get installed correctly when you do the installation for SQL Server 2019. I had to uninstall it and reinstall it and sqlcmd came back after the reinstallation. Not sure what it was.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlcmd -?` via PowerShell should return version information and usage guidelines, as in:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\xxx> sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 15.0.4123.1 NT
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

usage: Sqlcmd            [-U login id]          [-P password]
  [-S server]            [-H hostname]          [-E trusted connection]
  [-N Encrypt Connection][-C Trust Server Certificate]
  [-d use database name] [-l login timeout]     [-t query timeout]
  [-h headers]           [-s colseparator]      [-w screen width]
  [-a packetsize]        [-e echo input]        [-I Enable Quoted Identifiers]
  [-c cmdend]            [-L[c] list servers[clean output]]
  [-q "cmdline query"]   [-Q "cmdline query" and exit]
  [-m errorlevel]        [-V severitylevel]     [-W remove trailing spaces]
  [-u unicode output]    [-r[0|1] msgs to stderr]
  [-i inputfile]         [-o outputfile]        [-z new password]
  [-f  | i:[,o:]] [-Z new password and exit]
  [-k[1|2] remove[replace] control characters]
  [-y variable length type display width]
  [-Y fixed length type display width]
  [-p[1] print statistics[colon format]]
  [-R use client regional setting]
  [-K application intent]
  [-M multisubnet failover]
  [-b On error batch abort]
  [-v var = "value"...]  [-A dedicated admin connection]
  [-X[1] disable commands, startup script, environment variables [and exit]]
  [-x disable variable substitution]
  [-j Print raw error messages]
  [-g enable column encryption]
  [-G use Azure Active Directory for authentication]
  [-? show syntax summary]
PS C:\Users\xxx>
```

I have confirmed this using PowerShell on Windows Server 2019.  I would suggest trying `sqlcmd.exe -?` via the regular command-line, `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Just tried that and again. I get nothing. No error just goes back to C:\Windows\System32

Comment: Hannah Vernon funny part is it doesn't say that sqlcmd it not a valid cmdlet.